# Unity-iOS power consumption

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, guided-access

I am building an AR app with Unity for an exhbition. The app runs in Guided Access. I am checking the inactivity of the user, and after a certain time, I simply turn off the gameobjects on the screen. However, in this "low power" mode the battery is drained quickly and the device is very hot.

Are there any better options to optimize the power usage? Like in the Xcode project, turning off the Unity process when inactivity is detected? What is the proper way to measure the power usage of an iOS app? All I found is using the Xcode Organizer, but as I realized, it is data sent back from users for already published app.

Sorry if these are obvious things, this whole iOS platform and Apple stuff is very new to me.